# onload for populating telephone numbers on smartphones

Tags: javascript, events, dom, onload

I am attempting to code using a DOM event, `onload`, to populate a telephone number on smartphones when they visit a web page.

Previously, I used `onclick` on a redirect page when a button was clicked on a landing page. Now, when someone clicks on an Ad, and I provide a destination URL (which will be the redirect), all I want is the TFN to populate, that's all.

Previous:

```
window.location = "tel:1-8XX-XXX-XXXX"
```

Now:

```
window.onload = "tel:1-8XX-XXX-XXXX"
```

What am I missing? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using a redirect for a smartphone?   Just using an HTML element <a href="tel:1-8xx-xxx-xxxx">1-8xx-xxx-xxxx</a> will work on any smartphone.  The phone will automatically open the native phone dialer from the browser. I believe every major smartphone OS does this now and has for a while.  Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: Previously, we had to create the redirect to capture analytics from FB, so we used "onclick" on the same page. Now I plan on keeping this de facto "landing page" simple - using the URL as the destination so once a person is sent there the TFN populates. Thank you - when you are trying to see past the forest you can't see the first tree.   :)

Comment: Let me clarify my last reply - using the URL as the destination so once a person is sent there the native dialer fires with the TFN populated....I can get the TFN to show, but I want to skip past that event and have the native dialer appear.....